# numpy.vectorize: Why so slow?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, ipython, vectorization

The expit function, in scipy.special, is a vectorized sigmoid function. It computes 1 / (1+e^(-x)), which is complicated, probably involving a Taylor series.

I learned about the "fast sigmoid", 1 / (1 + abs(x)), which ought to be much faster -- but the builtin expit function massively outperforms it, even when I hand it as a lambda expression to numpy.vectorize.

Here's one way to test them:

```
from scipy.special import expit
data = np.random.rand(1000000)
```

The built-in, complicated sigmoid is fast:

```
%prun expit(data)

3 function calls in 0.064 seconds

Ordered by: internal time

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     1    0.064    0.064    0.064    0.064 <string>:1(<module>)
     1    0.000    0.000    0.064    0.064 {built-in method builtins.exec}
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

The simpler sigmoid is around 20 times slower:

```
%prun np.vectorize( lambda x: (x / (1 + abs(x)) + 1) / 2 )(data)

2000023 function calls in 1.992 seconds

Ordered by: internal time

 ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
1000001    1.123    0.000    1.294    0.000 <string>:1(<lambda>)
      1    0.558    0.558    1.950    1.950 function_base.py:2276(_vectorize_call)
1000001    0.170    0.000    0.170    0.000 {built-in method builtins.abs}
      4    0.098    0.025    0.098    0.025 {built-in method numpy.core.multiarray.array}
      1    0.041    0.041    1.991    1.991 function_base.py:2190(__call__)
      1    0.000    0.000    0.068    0.068 function_base.py:2284(<listcomp>)
      1    0.000    0.000    1.992    1.992 {built-in method builtins.exec}
      1    0.000    0.000    1.991    1.991 <string>:1(<module>)
      1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 function_base.py:2220(_get_ufunc_and_otypes)
      1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 function_base.py:2162(__init__)
      1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 function_base.py:2242(<listcomp>)
      2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 numeric.py:414(asarray)
      1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method numpy.core.umath.frompyfunc}
      1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 function_base.py:2266(<listcomp>)
      2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.isinstance}
      1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.len}
      1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'join' of 'str' objects}
      1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

Answer (score 10):

I'll just quote the the [vectorize docstring](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html): "The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop."

You want to make `1/(1 + abs(x))` fast.  numpy has a function called `numpy.abs` (also called [`numpy.absolute`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.absolute.html)--they are different names for the same object).  It computes the absolute value of each element of its argument, and it does this in C code, so it is fast.  Also, the Python built-in function `abs` knows how to dispatch arguments to objects that have the method `__abs__`, which numpy arrays do, so you can also use Python's `abs()` to compute the element-wise absolute value of a numpy array.  In the following, though, I'll use `np.abs`.

Here's an example of the use of `np.abs`:

```
In [25]: x = np.array([-2, -1.5, 0, 5, 10])

In [26]: np.abs(x)
Out[26]: array([  2. ,   1.5,   0. ,   5. ,  10. ])
```

Here's a comparision of the performance of `scipy.special.expit` and `1.0/(1 + np.abs(x))` for a large array `x`:

```
In [34]: from scipy.special import expit

In [35]: x = np.random.randn(100000)

In [36]: %timeit expit(x)
1000 loops, best of 3: 771 µs per loop

In [37]: %timeit 1.0/(1 + np.abs(x))
1000 loops, best of 3: 279 µs per loop
```

So `1.0/(1 + np.abs(x))` is quite a bit faster than `expit(x)`.

Comment: I tested; this definitely solves my problem. Thanks, Warren!