# Numpy ufunc.reduce SLOWER THAN applying native python reduce after ndarray.tolist?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, functional-programming

I enjoy using a lot of functional programming features when playing with Python lists. When I switch to Numpy for big dataset, I would expect that it is significantly more efficient than native Python list operations over `ndarray.tolist()` since it is stored differently.

So when I try to apply `map`, `reduce`, `filter` such FP things on Numpy array, I first search over the Numpy's doc for some "optimized things". And what I get is [numpy.ufunc.reduce](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html) it seems to be the right thing. However, for curiosity, I did a simple test on both approaches:

1. Use Numpy reduce

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array(range(100000000))
adf = lambda res, a: res + a
u_adf = np.frompyfunc(adf, 2, 1)
print(u_adf.reduce(a, initial=0))
```

2. Use `ndarray.tolist()` and then use Python native reduce

```py
import numpy as np
from functools import reduce

a = np.array(range(100000000))
adf = lambda res, a: res + a
print(reduce(adf, a.tolist(), 0))
```

Here comes the most unexpected thing:

```sh
> python 1.py
4999999950000000
python 1.py  28.00s user 5.71s system 102% cpu 32.925 total

> python 2.py
4999999950000000
python 2.py  26.38s user 6.38s system 103% cpu 31.792 total
```

The so-called "stupid" approach is actually the more efficient way?

How can that be? Can anyone please explain this for me? And hopefully gives some advice on using functional programming features on Numpy arrays.

Appreciate ^_^

Comment: `frompyfunc` is not too dissimilar to `vectorize`. I would refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40966369/8676953

Comment: Have you tested `np.add.reduce` or `np.sum`?

Comment: @de1 oh really, I thought that would be something different :( thank you for pointing that out

Comment: @hpaulj thank for your advice! summation here is only for testing, I'm look for a way to apply `reduce` (i.e. functional programming), not simply the sum of the array ;D

Comment: The `reduce` of compiled `ufunc` is reasonably fast. `frompyfunc` creates a `ufunc`, but does not compile it.  In my experience its speed is comparable to list code.  The `numpy` storage is optimized for `c` code that can work directly with the `c` array.  Otherwise any python level iteration on an array is slower.