# Python function not accepting arrays as inputs

Tags: python, function, numpy, loops, definition

This function works well with a single input as seen in Example 1 but when I want to run it using arrays as inputs it fails (as stated in Example 2). I don't want to use a for loop to calculate the function for each element of the d, l, and b arrays. Because it is slow. What I want to do is that the function has to use i-th element of each array of d, l, and b as an input and calculate the results and give the results as an array which has the same size d, l, and b. In the Example 2, the result should be a 2-element array which is array([17.8, 22.4]). But it is not working as I expected.

```
import numpy as np

def mydef(d, l, b):
    dd = 0.1
    ds = np.arange(0, d+dd, dd)
    return np.sum(l*ds+b)

#Example 1
print(mydef(.2, 3, 4))
print(mydef(.3, 4, 5))
#Example 2
d=np.array([.2, .3])
l=np.array([3, 4])
b=np.array([4, 5])
print(mydef(d, l, b))
```

Example 2 gives

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: The traceback should show the error is in the `arange`.  That function only works with scalars.  Review its docs!  Did you ever test  a simpler `np.arange(0, d)`?

Comment: What did you expect `ds` to be?

Comment: @hpaulj no, it is not working. It is like integrating a function in the range of (0, d) using a step of dd. But I can't make it.

Comment: for `d = 0.2`, `ds = [0, 0.1, 0.2]`

Comment: And for 0.3?  For `[.2, .3]`?  I don't think you have really this through.

Comment: for `d = 0.3`, `ds = [0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3]`

Comment: Those are 2 different length arrays!  How are those supposed to work with the 2 element `b` and `l`?

Comment: for `d=[.2, .3]`, `l=[3, 4]`, and `b=[4, 5]` I want the function returns a 2-element array which is `[mydef(d[0], l[0], b[0]), mydef(d[1], l[1], b[1])]`

Comment: I asked how those different length `ds` are supposed to work with `b` and `l`.  If you don't want loops you need to use some sort of 2d array calculation.  Focus on what's happening **inside** your function, not on how you call it.

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with hpaulj, the following could help you:

```py
import numpy as np

def mydef(d, l, b):
    dd = 0.1
    ds = np.arange(0, d+dd, dd)
    return np.sum(l*ds+b)

vfunc = np.vectorize(mydef)

dd = 0.3
d=np.array([.2, .3])
l=np.array([3, 4])
b=np.array([4, 5])

output = vfunc(d, l, b)
output
array([17.8, 22.4])
```

Note that np.vectorize is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. See also [numpy.vectorize: Why so slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40955550/numpy-vectorize-why-so-slow) and https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html.
If you really want pure speed, then you should follow hpaulj.